# Version control for aggregatation of multiple projects using Maven / Git

Tags: git, maven, configuration-management

I have BigSystem which consists of multiple SubSystems. Each SubSystem is an individual project which compiles into an application, has its own release cycle and Git repository, and is separately maintained. BigSystem is simply an aggregation of the SubSystems it consists of.

I would like to tag and maintain versions of BigSystem relative to specific versions of SubSystems i.e. By building BigSystem-1.1.0, I would in effect be building SubSystemA-1.0.1, SubSystemB-2.2.0, and SubSystemC-2.5.0.

```
BigSystem-1.0.0
  SubSystemA-1.0.1
  SubSystemB-2.0.0
  SubSystemC-2.0.4

BigSystem-1.1.0
  SubSystemA-1.0.1
  SubSystemB-2.2.0
  SubSystemC-2.5.0

BigSystem-1.2.0-SNAPSPHOT
  SubSystemA-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
  SubSystemB-2.2.0
  SubSystemC-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I've been exploring Maven aggregation, Maven inheritance, and Git submodules to achieve this, but I haven't been able to find a clean solution. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git submodule will help aggregating the **source dependencies**, meaning `BigSystem` will record the exact SHA1 of each SubSystem source repos.

That is separate from how each SubSystem is *built*: it can be build using:

- source dependencies, in which case you build all the dependencies each time you need to produce a SubSystem delivery
- binary dependency, in which case the source a SubSystemA includes a pom.xml which *declares* the exact version and dependencies it needs to compile.
  That also means the deliveries produced by the compilation of a SubSystem are stored in an artifact repository like Nexus.

Comment: I used submodules in the end, although the workflow is pretty clunky.